# Microservice rollback approach if e2e test automation fails in CICD

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, automated-tests, microservices, cicd

When a new feature of a microservice is merged into development branch, is it always deployed to Kubernetes test environment.

- If yes, what happens if e2e tests fail? Is the microservice deployment rolled back?
- Is automated rollback common in CICD in the industry right now?
- Is there any other way to make e2e blackbox tests without deploying to Kubernetes test environment?

I could not find a good example about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a new feature of a microservice is merged into development
> branch, is it always deployed to Kubernetes test environment.

**Yes**, you are right

> If yes, what happens if e2e tests fail? Is the microservice deployment
> rolled back?

Since it's a **development** environment ideally it should be fine to run the broken version however more depends on the requirements or architecture you are planning to follow.

> Is automated rollback common in CICD in the industry right now?

Yes, that's common however it would be better to keep it as **Manual** action, you might have a scenario where you want to deploy the version while e2e failing.

The benefit of **Manual action** as require might get change and have to deploy feature in which integration testing failing or something else.

> Is there any other way to make e2e blackbox tests without deploying to
> Kubernetes test environment?

You can do the subsystem or small portion testing in CI/CD, **e2e** also you can automate on **CI/CD** side and integrate the **Kubernetes** service accessible to the **CI** server for testing.